# Looping through a file, a set of lines by lines

Tags: java, file, loops, netbeans

I have an issue with reading through a .dat file.
Currently, I know how to read a .dat/.txt file, but this one is a little tricky for me.

So I have a set of data like this:

**test.dat**

```
Sunday
Scuba Diving Classes
Mr.Jones
N/A
Yes

Sunday
Sailing
Mr. Jackson
N/A
Yes

Sunday
Generation Next
Ms.Steele
N/A
Yes

Monday
Helping Hands
Ms.Wafa
ANX0
No
```

What I need to do with this file is to go through the file record by record, and if a string *activityname* .equals to the Name of the activity (e.g. Scuba Diving Classes), the variables starting with **C** are set for viewing. Here's the coding for it:

```
try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.dat"));

                int numberOfLines = readLines();
                numberOfLines = numberOfLines / 6;

                for(int i=0;i < numberOfLines; i++)
                {
                    String CDay = reader.readLine();
                    String CActivityName = reader.readLine();
                    String CSupervisor = reader.readLine();
                    String CLocation = reader.readLine();
                    String CPaid = reader.readLine();
                    String nothing = reader.readLine();

                    if(CActivityName.equals(activityName))
                    {
                        txtDay.setText(CDay);
                        txtSupervisor.setText(CSupervisor);
                        txtLocation.setText(CLocation);

                        //If it Activity is paid, then it is shown as paid via radiobutton
                        if(CPaid.equals("Yes"))
                                {
                                    radioYes.setSelected(rootPaneCheckingEnabled);
                                }
                        if(CPaid.equals("No"))
                                {
                                    radioNo.setSelected(rootPaneCheckingEnabled);
                                }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        reader.close();
                    }
                }
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
                Logger.getLogger(AddActivity.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }
    }
```

I've used the numberoflines variable to go through the file, but my logic is flawed, and I have no idea how to go through this

**Current status and error of method**

Currently, this method only reads the first record *Scuba Diving Classes*, and does not go through the entire file when the if condition is false.

Help!

Comment: You're closing the reader as soon as you meet an activity whose name is not equal to activityName. Don't.

Comment: That worked!!! Didn't see my logic flaw
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Currently, this method … does not go through the entire file when the if condition is false.

To figure out why, take a look at the `else` block:

```
else
{
    reader.close();
}
```

This means that you are closing the `BufferedReader` before you have finished reading the file. You don't need to put anything in the `else` block there.

Comment: Well JB Nizet did give me the answer just a minute ago, but still, thank you + the clear explanation!

Answer (score 1):

I see JB Net comment helped you. Also in general you should close a IO variable (file, data or other) in a finally block like so:

```
InputStream is = null;
try{
    //open streams, do work
}catch(...){

}finally{
//seperate try catch here to make sure it does not affect anything else, just close one resource per try catch
try{
    if(is != null){
        is.close()
    }catch(Exception ...){
        //one line log
    }
}
```

In java 7 you have try with resource but not tried that :)

Comment: Is there a possibility for future errors of the finally block isn't present? Sorry I'm new and not too familiar with the finally block...

Comment: Not sure I understood you. Are you asking can there be errors if you do not use a finally block? If so yes - can end up with files you cannot write to when your program is running or sockets and other handles being exhausted by your program. More important in iterative processing/ server apps